# TINYMCE - How to turn off all auto replacements?

Tags: tinymce

Is there any way to turn off all auto replacements in TINYMCE ?

Its replacing my `<b>` tags to `<strong>` and  a
full url such as `<a href="http://example.com"` is getting turned into `<a href="../example.com"`
and so on.

I tried to use those 3:

```
    extended_valid_elements : '*[*]',
    cleanup : false,
    verify_html : false
```

No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `<b>` and `<i>` tags instead of `<strong>` and `<em>` you can use this setting in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
extended_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em",  //force strong-->b and em-->i
```

TinyMCE also has a variety of options for managing URLs:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/

You should look at those options to see how they can help address your URL issue.